# How to insert and fetch to-many relationship entities in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Please I need a sample code how to save and fetch data in a one to many relationship? This is my two `NSManagedObject` subclasses. I managed to do the save and fetch for one to one relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data save code

```
UserDefinedInterests *aAserDefineInterrest1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserDefinedInterests" inManagedObjectContext:context];

aAserDefineInterrest1.name = @"PPP";
aAserDefineInterrest1.categoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:168004];

UserDefinedInterests *aAserDefineInterrest2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserDefinedInterests" inManagedObjectContext:context];

aAserDefineInterrest2.name = @"QQQ";
aAserDefineInterrest2.categoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12248004];

UserDefinedInterests *aAserDefineInterrest3 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserDefinedInterests" inManagedObjectContext:context];

aAserDefineInterrest3.name = @"RRR";
aAserDefineInterrest3.categoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3534535];

NSMutableSet *userDefineInterests = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:aAserDefineInterrest, nil];

[aTopic addUserDefinedInterests:userDefineInterests];
```

Data fetch code

```
// Test listing topic details from the store
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeEntity"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (TopicDetails *aTopic in fetchedObjects) {

    ......

    NSSet *pp = aTopic.userDefinedInterests;

    for (some *somearray in pp.allObjects) {


    }
}
```